# Горизонтальный скрол по центру

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Такая задача:
при загрузке страницы (если есть горизонтальный скрол) перемещать видимую область по центру (по горизонтали).
Воспользовался библиотекой scrollTo.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.scrollTo({"left": "50%"});
});
```

но что-то не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QR7sa/4/

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <style>
    #box {
        width: 5000px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #Aff;
    }
  </style>  
  <body>
    <div id="box"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var scroll = ( document.documentElement.scrollWidth - $(window).width() )/2;
            if(document.documentElement.scrollWidth > $(window).width() ) {
                $(document).scrollLeft(scroll);
            }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 left_scr = ($(document).width() - $(window).width())/2;
 $(document).scrollLeft(left_scr);
});
```

Информация отсюда: http://forum.enterin.ru/thread-3.html